# MYSQL, Copy selected fields from one table to another

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

In MySQL, How do I copy a FIELD with all RECORDS from `TABLE1` to `TABLE2` which corresponds to a primary key ie: `EMPLOYEE no.`?

Comment: What are the fields in the tables? What have you tried so far?

Comment: are you trying to do a SELECT INTO statement?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Try this

```
INSERT INTO `table2` (`field_name2`) SELECT `field_name` FROM `table1`
```

Comment: this will insert all data from table1 to table2.

Comment: Given that this is the accepted answer I'll assume that the OP posted the incorrect question.

Comment: Make sure you fully understand what this query does BEFORE you run it (which is insert new records - it DOES NOT "update" existing records corresponding to a primary key, which is what the OP was asking). If you're not sure you understand that, back up your data before you run it.

Comment: This is wrong answer. It should be deleted

Answer (score 100):

If you mean you want to *update* one table's column using another table's column, then here are some options:

1. A join:

   ```
   UPDATE table1 AS t1
     INNER JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.EmpoyeeNo = t2.EmployeeNo
   SET t1.SomeColumn = t2.SomeColumn
   ```

   Alternatively it could be a left join:

   ```
   UPDATE table1 AS t1
     LEFT JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.EmpoyeeNo = t2.EmployeeNo
   SET t1.SomeColumn = t2.SomeColumn
   ```

   which would essentially empty (set to NULL) the values where no match occurred.
2. A subquery:

   ```
   UPDATE table1
   SET SomeColumn = (
     SELECT SomeColumn
     FROM table2
     WHERE EmployeeNo = table1.EmployeeNo
   )
   ```

   This is equivalent to the left join solution in #1.

Note that in all cases it is assumed that a row in `table1` can match no more than one row in `table2`.

Answer (score 30):

The query for copy data from one table to another is:

```sql
INSERT INTO `table2` (`field1`, `field2`)
    SELECT `field1`, `field2` FROM `table1`
```

If you want to copy only  selected values, then use where clause in query

```sql
INSERT INTO `table2` (`field1`, `field2`)
    SELECT `field1`, `field2` FROM `table1`
    WHERE `field1` = condition
```

Answer (score 6):

```
update
  table1 t1
  join table2 t2 on t2.field = t1.field
set
  t1.field1 = t2.matchingfield
where
  t1.whatever = t2.whatever
```

Comment: What does the t1 and t2 mean in this equation?

Comment: @Eoin They're called `table alias` They are used to simplify the name of the tables. So that you can type less. You could also add `AS` => `UPDATE table1 AS t1 ...`

Comment: Nice! Moreover, it works well without the `where t1.whatever = t2.whatever` filter.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this to copy all the records from `table1` into `table2` with a condition.

```
Insert into table2  select  * from table1 where field1=condition
```

Comment: Note that the column _order_ in `table1` must exactly match the column _order_ in `table2`.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose if the table structure is as follows.

TableA - Col1, Col2 ,Col3
TableB - Col1, Col2 ,Col3

There is no need to select all column of the table to transfer data from 1 table to another table in same databse.
You can copy (insert) the rows from TableA to TableB.

Code as follows -

```
Insert into TableB (Col1, Col2 ,Col3)
Select Col1, Col2 ,Col3 from TableA
```

You can also do this -

```
Insert into TableB (Col1, Col2, Col3) 
Select * from TableA
```

Both codes work , you need to see your requirement.

Generic code -

```
INSERT INTO table2 (column1, column2, column3, ...)
SELECT column1, column2, column3, ...
FROM table1
WHERE condition;
```

You can add 'Where' condition if you need.

Thank you!!!

Answer (score -1):

INSERT INTO `table_1`(`column-1`, `column-2`) SELECT column-1, column-2 FROM table_2;

Comment: this question has received a lot of answers already. please compare your answer to the other answers and try to see if yours provides anything **new**. If so, please explain why, because it is not obvious to me

Comment: @K. Salabir welcome to the community thanks for providing an answer.

Answer (score -2):

`Insert into Delivery (DeliveredDate, appid, DownloadSize, UploadSize) select Delivered, Appid, DownloadSize,UploadSize from Delivery_Summary;`

Comment: A code only answer is not high quality.   A better answer would explain what the code does and how it solves the problem.