# How to copy some column from a table to another mysql

Tags: mysql, copy

i have two tables like:

table 1:

```
|A|B|C|D|E|F|G|H|I|J|
```

table 2:

```
|A|C|D|E|G|H|J|K|L|M|N|O|P|
```

i have to copy some columns from table 2 to table 1.
What i try is:

```
INSERT INTO `table 1` (`C`,`D`,`E`,`G`,`J`)
     SELECT `C`,`D`,`E`,`G`,`J` FROM `table 2` WHERE 
     `table 1`.`A` = `table 2`.`A`;
```

but it result :

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'table 1.A' in 'where clause'
```

where is the error? can someone help me?

MY ERROR IS THAT I DON'T HAVE TO INSERT NEW ROWS, BUT UPDATE THE ROWS THAT MATCH THE COLUMN A... in which way i have to edit my query? thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this::

```
INSERT INTO `table1` (`C`,`D`,`E`,`G`,`J`) VALUES
     (SELECT `C`,`D`,`E`,`G`,`J` FROM `table2` WHERE 
     `table1`.`A` = `table2`.`A`);
```

**Edited::**

If you only need to update then ::

```
    update table1 
    inner join table2 on table1.A = table2.A
    set 
    table1.C=table2.C, 
    table1.D=table2.D,
    table1.E=table2.E, 
    table1.G=table2.G,
    table1.J=table2.J
    WHERE 1=1
    ;
```

Comment: Edited to add ", table2" in first line of update query.

Comment: @SashiKant Was your UPDATE query tested?  I have modified it to suit my db tables, but it is failing with error: `#1054 - Unknown column '{table2}.{appropriateprimaryidentifier}' in 'where clause'`  I'm going to have to downvote this one until it is adjusted or proven to be correct.  (I am moving columns from an old copy to a new copy of the same table -- there will be no column conflicts and the table names and primary identifiers are correct.)

Comment: I ended up using the LEFT JOIN from http://stackoverflow.com/a/11168786/2943403  You should update or remove your edited content because it is incorrect.

Comment: @brett : Updated the answer. Kindly check

Comment: Hey @mickmackusa , sorry for the late response. Have updated my answer. Please check now.

Comment: I am not at my computer to check, but thank you for editing.  You should be capitalizing all mysql keywords and `WHERE 1=1` is useless.

Comment: @mickmackusa : The only purpose of `where 1=1` is to give a hint to the user, where the conditions need to be added :)
Thanks

Comment: Then you should probably explain that in your code-only answer.  You shouldn't assume that all future researchers will understand what the different parts of your snippets do.

Comment: can't understand how this answer got accepted. the first query cannot work. if it's an insert there is no entry in the first table to compare with so the where clause in the sub-select makes no sense. Also the error in the OP would be thrown here too, because in the subselect table1 is never introduced either in the from or in a join clause, hence `Unknown column 'table 1.A' in 'where clause'`

The update part is correct.

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT INTO `table 1` (`A`,`C`,`D`,`E`,`G`,`J`)
SELECT `t2`.`A`, `t2`.`C`, `t2`.`D`, `t2`.`E`, `t2`.`G`, `t2`.`J`
FROM `table 2` AS t2
INNER JOIN `table 1` AS t1
ON `t2`.`A` = `t1`.`A`
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `C` = VALUES(`C`), `D` = VALUES(`D`), `E` = VALUES(`E`), `G` = VALUES(`G`), `J` = VALUES(`J`)
```

I don't see any JOIN in your given query.

[**ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)