# Copying two columns from one table to another

Tags: mysql

Couldn't find exactly what I'm looking for anywhere else.

So I have table 1

```
users
----------

id
username
password
bio
isuser
email
```

and table 2

```
wp_users
----------

id
user_login
nice_username
password
email
```

There are 500 rows in 'wp_users' table. I would like to copy 'id' and 'user_login' into the users table ('id' and 'username') for each row.

How can I do this? MySQL isn't my strong point lol.

UPDATE: I have updated the tables above as I tried to simplify it but in return got the wrong solution.

Comment: Refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11168402/mysql-copy-selected-fields-from-one-table-to-another

Comment: Didn't properly type my question out. There are other values in the tables I didn't mention. The above answer only selects one column to insert into the other table, I would like to select two and don't know the format of this. thanks ( I have updated my question )

Comment: Refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11517913/how-to-copy-some-column-from-a-table-to-another-mysql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an `INSERT` - `SELECT` statement:

```
INSERT INTO `users` (id,username,password,bio,isuser,email) SELECT id,
user_login,null,null,null,null FROM `wp_users`;
```

You can put another fields or even static data on each field of the `SELECT` part. I've put nulls just to illustrate.

Just remember that anything the `SELECT` fetches will be inserted in the table the `INSERT` statement says (so you can use clauses like `WHERE`, `GROUP BY`, `HAVING`, etc on the `SELECT` part).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for a simple insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO users (id,username)
SELECT W.id,
       W.user_login
FROM   wp_users W
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL
                   FROM   users U
                   WHERE  U.ID = W.ID);
```

I am assuming the other columns in your users table are nullable, if not, you can add more columns to the select statement with the values in you'd like for the other columns.

You haven't mentioned any other keys or constraints, so I have assumed there aren't any.

I have also provided a check in the `WHERE` clause to see if a row already exists for the same ID, so you only insert a row for each ID once.